# CSS for Wordpress in a specific post

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been trying for several hours to get some images to display horizontally in a Wordpress post.  When I click "text" , I can add a div class so I have tried adding inline styling to the div (as I do not want to adjust the entire css for the entire site).  I installed a plugin "custom css" which doesn't seem to work either.

I have also tried styling the image itself

```
img style="display: inline; margin: 0 5px;" src="blah blah"
```

I am fresh out of ideas and ready to pull out what hair I have left.

Comment: Have you tried `display: inline-block;` in the inline styles? Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: Yes I tried inline-block.  It's a post on a Wordpress page (that never got put up).  The post/page are irrelevant.  There doesn't seem to be a way to make the Wordpress take the formatting.  Just curious if anyone has found a way to get the css to take for Wordpress.

Comment: There is no real problem with your approach, but when you are asking about getting the css to take, you may have a theme or plugin that is imposing styles with the !important flag. That's why it may help to see the page. In the WordPress editor, if you set the image alignment to left which floats it to the left, may help you get them to layout inline.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem completely!

if you want to add style to specific post images, for example, images of the post with id `140`, add `post_class` function and then use `.post-140 img` class to add style to the specific post.

[post_class function refrence](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/), [the_post_thumbnail function refrecne](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

or if you want to style thumbnails you can add class to thumbnails like this: `the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'class name' ) );`

hope to be useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom style or override a specific post only without affecting to other posts, 2 approaches can be used.

1. Using a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/postpage-specific-custom-css/
2. If the use case is simple, we can add a custom style as follows inside the custom CSS area in Appearance -> Customize -> General -> Custom CSS/Js

To add a new style

```
#post-[WP-ID-OF-THE-POST] { /* YOUR STYLE HERE */ }
```

To override an existing style

```
#post-[WP-ID-OF-THE-POST] .nav_area{ /* YOUR STYLE HERE */ }
```

Eg:-

```
   #post-100 {
    /* YOUR STYLE HERE */
    }
```

100 is the ID of the specific post.

Reference: https://theme4press.com/give-wordpress-post-unique-style/